# Angular file upload is not working in kotlin's web view

Tags: angular, kotlin, file-upload, webview

I'm loading an angular page which has a file upload functionality in kotlin web view.

I used simple
<input type = "file" accept = "application/pdf,image/jpeg" id ="file" (change) = "FileUpload($event) />
This is working in web browser but in android nothing happens after click.

After some research I found that my implementation won't work in web view of kotlin.

Can someone provide me the solution which have to work in web browser as well as in android app.

I tried few file upload packages ngx-filepond ngx-file-drop but nothing worked.